# vsftpd hanging when using pam_exec or pam_script

Tags: vsftpd, pam

I have VSFTPD integrated with pam_mysql, allowing me to successfully login to an FTP server using accounts kept in a mysql database.

I need to automatically create a directory for the user if it is the first time they've logged into the server. I've seen suggestions to use pam_script or pam_exec to achieve this.

As a test I've revised my `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` configuration to include the following line:

```
account optional pam_exec.so debug log=/tmp/pam_exec.log /etc/pam-script/test.sh
```

The script just echoes the user:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $PAM_USER
```

In `/var/log/auth.log` I can see that the script is being called:

```
Jan 16 17:15:44 ip-172-31-8-61 vsftpd: pam_exec(vsftpd:auth): Calling /etc/pam-script/dir.sh ...
```

However the FTP login doesn't complete. The connection hangs. All subsequent connections fail and I have to restart the service to get it to respond.

I've ruled out problems with the configuration/script by also tweaking the PAM config for  SSHD logins, this seems to work fine.

I've also tested this using the pam_script module and get similar results when the `pam_script_auth` script is called.

The problem seems to be that VSFTP isn't able to complete a login if there are additional steps in the PAM configuration. I've tried different settings (auth, account) and different requirements levels (optional, required) without any success.

Anyone have any ideas?

Update: Ubuntu 12.04. Using a tweaked version of [VSFTP as described here](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2012/10/making-vsftpd-with-chrooted-users-work-again/)

Comment: I have the same issue on Debian with:  pam_exec, pam_script and a custom pam module which uses system or popen function .After some researches, I found it could be a bug, fixed on Redhat:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1198259

Answer (score 2):

I confirm this is a bug on Debian / Ubuntu and native versions of vsftpd. Any PAM module calling a subprocess will block or hang vsftpd (e.g. pam_exec, pam_script, custom pam module involving system or popen calls).

I solved it by building centos sources on my Debian:

```
apt-get install vsftpd
cd /usr/local/src
git clone  https://git.centos.org/git/centos-git-common.git
cp ./centos-git-common/*.sh /usr/local/sbin
git clone https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/vsftpd
cd /usr/local/src/vsftpd
git checkout c7
get_sources.sh
cd SOURCES
tar xvzf vsftpd-3.0.2.tar.gz
mv vsftpd-3.0.2/* .
git apply *-3.0.2-*.patch
sed -i -e 's/vsf_findlibs.sh`/vsf_findlibs.sh` -lcap/g' Makefile
sed -i -e 's/undef VSF_BUILD_SSL/define VSF_BUILD_SSL/g' builddefs.h
make
cp vsftpd /usr/sbin
```

vsftpd won't hang anymore and you will be able to call system() function from your PAM modules. fork and exec still won't work properly for some reason.

Comment: Been struggling to get pam_exec to work with vsftpd....now I understand why.
Submitted a Debian bug [report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=952421)
(it that's the course of my problem)

Comment: @MrCalvin did you receive any update on your bug report?

Comment: Nope. And I have submitted several bugs relation to vsftpd and nothing happens. I've come to the conclussion vsftpd and related projects are a thing of the past and in practice dead. Future is SCP/ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked a while back but I ran into similar issues on Debian, namely hanging vsftpd process when adding pam_exec to the chain.
For me the issue was that it was not enough to add

```
session_support=YES
```

to the vsftpd config file but to also put

```
@include common-session
```

into `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` which I had commented out following some guides about virtual-only users for vsftpd.
So the complete pam file looks like this for me:

```
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth    required        pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/etc/ftppasswd
account required        pam_permit.so
session optional        pam_exec.so type=close_session log=/var/log/session.log /etc/pam_session.sh
@include common-session
```

(My use case is to process uploaded files once a specific ftp user logs out)

Answer (score 0):

Check your suexec logs.  Maybe your directory structure is in a non-standard location for vsftpd.  Also, I think you need more in your pam configuration file.

Here is what my pam config looks like:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/vsftpd 
#%PAM-1.0

# Auth in MySQL
auth requisite pam_mysql.so user=readonly passwd=readonly host=somehost db=somedb table=accounts usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=pass crypt=3 
auth required pam_script.so onerr=success dir=/etc/pam-script

# Account in MySQL
account required pam_mysql.so user=readonly passwd=readonly host=somehost db=somedb table=accounts usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=pass crypt=3


$ cat /etc/pam-script/pam_script_auth
#!/bin/sh
# Purpose: create the users's homedir and default message
#
# The evnironment variable $PAM_USER is passed on from PAM
# layer to this script via pam_script.so

if [ ! -d "/opt/ftp/$PAM_USER" ]; then
  /bin/su - ftp -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/env mkdir /opt/ftp/$PAM_USER"
  /bin/su - ftp -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/env chmod 751 /opt/ftp/$PAM_USER"
  /bin/su - ftp -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/env cat /etc/vsftpd /vsftpd.banner.homedir.txt > /opt/ftp/$PAM_USER/.message"
  /bin/su - ftp -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/env cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.banner.homedir.txt > /opt/ftp/$PAM_USER/README.first"
fi

$ cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.int.21.conf
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
message_file=.message
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=ftp
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/ssl/

guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp
local_root=/opt/ftp/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
banner_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.banner.server.txt

pasv_min_port=20005
pasv_max_port=30005
pasv_address=10.10.10.10

## FTPS (21) Config Changes
listen_port=21
ftp_data_port=20
listen_address=10.10.10.123
```

It has been a while since I looked at this so hope it helps.

Comment: Hi nick, I'm also trying to get this up and running. I'm running an aws ami 64bit machine. I've been able to get my ftp server up and running as well as connect to it. I'm struggling to get it to automatically create the home dirs. Anyhow my question has to do with the pam_script_auth. Is this a script I need to download and modify, or is it a script I need to create? I must admit, I'm a noob when it comes to linux and scripts. I manually created it and it fails to connect. Please advise. Thanks.